# Screencapture in NetBeans for Android

Tags: android, netbeans

I am thinking of making a move to Net Beans but one thing I cant figure out is how to take a snapshot of the screen. I know eclipse has this capability.

Comment: If I may ask, why NetBeans? With Eclipse you can use the ADT plugin.. last I checked there was nothing of the sort for NetBeans.

Comment: Other people on my team are using netbeans is the main reason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [standalone DDMS](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/ddms.html) for that. You'll find it in the `tools/` directory of your SDK installation.